# How to make copy of MutableList in Kotlin?

Tags: list, kotlin, mutable

So, I just started out with Kotlin and tried to solve "min steps for a knight to reach a destination on a chessboard" problem.
Here is my code:

```
fun knightSteps(i:Int,j:Int,a:Int,b:Int,board:Int,c :Int,d:Int,visited : MutableList<Pair<Int,Int>>,steps:Int):Int{
    // (i,j) start (a,b)knight moves (c,d) destination visited - visited positions board - size of board
    if(i==c && j==d) return steps
    if(isValid(Pair(i,j),board)){
        val v = visited
        v.add(Pair(i,j))

        var possible = mutableListOf<Int>()
        if(Pair(i+a,j+b) !in v ) {
            possible.add(knightSteps(i + a, j + b, a, b, board,c,d, v, 1 + steps))
        }
        if(Pair(i+a,j-b) !in v ) {
            if(i==1&&j==3) println("YES!!")
            possible.add(knightSteps(i + a, j - b, a, b, board,c,d, v, 1 + steps))
        }
        .
        .  // rest of other 8 possible moves
        .
        possible.removeAll{it==-1}
        if(possible.size==0){
            return -1
        }
        //println(possible)
        return possible.min()!!
    }
    return -1
}
```

But once it passes the first 'if' condition the 'visited' and 'v' mutable lists are changing their values as a result the `println("YES!!")` in second 'if' is never executed.

So the function is changing them.. again if i change `val v = visited.toMutableList(`) it enters into infinite loop! Can someone help.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. But yes, when you add values into `visited` they will be added to the argument of your function (also visible outside the function) and also: `v` and `visited` are pointing to the same object. It does not matter if you add to the one or the other, the list will contain a new element afterwards (`val v = visited` does not create any copy)

Comment: @s1m0nw1 that's exactly what I want to hear! So, how can I make it not to change it's value?

Comment: First of all change the parameter type to List, then in your method you could copy it with toMutableList

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in java and kotlin almost everything is being passed as reference. But in kotlin you have compile-time verified ability to make any `MutableList` immutable - just change method argument type from `MutableList` to `List`

Answer (score 2):

When you add values to `visited` they will be added to the argument of your function (i.e. are also visible outside the function). Also, `v` and `visited` are pointing to the **same object**. It doesn't matter which variable you use to add elements to, the list will contain a new element afterwards. The statement `val v = visited` *does not create any copy*.
For copying a list you can do `visited.toList()` which under the hood basically maps  to a call of `ArrayList(visited)`.